# Cant make AJAX with JQuery work in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am working on a Rails project and try to use $.post to get some data from the server, but nothing happens. Does anyone see whats wrong?

HTML File

```
<a id="ta" role="button" class="btn">tzt</a>
<div id="ggg">Code goes here</div>
```

.js file

```
$ ->
$('#ta').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $.post "/hype", (data)
    $("#ggg").html data
```

routes.rb

```
match '/hype',    to: 'items#xxx'
```

controller.rb

```
def xxx
@item = Item.last
return render :text => "New Text"
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing'? Is the click event not fired? Does the click event not POST? Is data not returned? Use Firebug to keep an eye on what's happening in the browser, that way you can home in on the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .js file should be as such

```
$ ->
  $('#ta').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $.post "/hype", (data) ->
      $("#ggg").html data
```

Need the function call after the post

Comment: It is indented in the code :) It was just something wrong that happend when I wrote the question here.

Answer (score 0):

try :
.js file

```
 $.post('/hype', function(data) {
      $("#ggg").html(data);
    });
```

controller.rb

```
def xxx
@item = Item.last
render :text => "New Text"
end
```

to be sure that the url is ok  just test it in your browser address bar